# Tableau dashboard filter body-text display

Tags: filter, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have week filter in my tableau dashboard, but the body of it has just numbers 1, 2, 3.. displayed. How can I have them displayed as
Week 1
Week 2
Week 3 and so on.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can make a calculated field, call it "Week Filter" and in the body of the calculation type: "Week " + STR([Week]), and use this new field as a filter.